# Immutable design with an ORM: How are sessions managed?

Tags: database, functional-programming, orm

If I were to make a site with a mutable language like C# and use NHibernate, I would normally approach sessions with the idea of making them as create only when needed and dispose at request end.  This has helped with keeping a session for multiple transactions by a user but keep it from staying open too long where the state might be corrupted.

In an immutable system, like F#, I would think I shouldn't do this because it supposes that a single session could be updated constantly by any number of inserts/updates/deletes/ect...   I'm not against the "using" solution since I would think that connecting pooling will help cut down on the cost of connecting every time, but I don't know if all database systems do connection pooling.  It just seems like there should be a better way that doesn't compromise the immutability goal.

Should I just do a simple "using" block per transaction or is there a better pattern for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of taking a wild guess here since I'm absolutely unfamiliar with F#, but it sounds like our talking about a context manager type structure similiar to the one outlined in this article:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a shared ObjectContext instance.
/// </summary>
public NorthwindObjectContext ObjectContext
{
    get
    {
        string ocKey = "ocm_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(ocKey))
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(ocKey, new NorthwindObjectContext());
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[ocKey] as NorthwindObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Complete Article here:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx

In the past I've used a "one context per request" idea and love it.. the "using" method is just too small of a scope for me.

Answer (score 0):

To be language agnostic the issue you are talking about is binding a connection/transaction to some "context" and then doing some very stateful and procedural communication to the connection and then disposing/closing/committing the connection/transaction and then finally removing the connection/transaction from the "context".

Worse in most languages this "context" is maintained in a ThreadLocal which is sort of equivalent to a global variable.

My guess is F# probably does what C# does but if you did want to do this in a more  FP way I would look at implementing it as a Monad and see how Haskell manages database stuff.